# Model Binding PHP-Type $POST Data in ASP.NET MVC 3 Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm dealing with a post from a javascript script on my page that is sending data to my action method in the format:

```
stuff[value1]=value1
stuff[value2]=value2
stuff[value3]=value3
```

...like a PHP hash.  If I were programming this in PHP, I would retrieve the values into a hash by doing something like

```
$data = $POST['stuff']
```

Any way I can easily deal with this data in an ASP.NET MVC way?  I have used a FormCollection parameter to my action method, and it captures data such that each key is like stuff[value1] and the value is value1.  I can do that, but the real key is inside the [], and I would rather not have to parse out the real keys from strings.  I've also tried

```
Dictionary<String, object> stuff
```

but that didn't bind any data at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
?stuff[0].Key=1&stuff[0].value=2&stuff[1].Key=1&stuff[1].value=2
&stuff[2].Key=1&stuff[2].value=2;
```

will be binded to:

```
public ActionResult Foo(Dictionary<int,object> stuff)
{
}
```

Read [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for this kind of complex scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I glanced at this before, but I did not read it cover to cover.  Your solution did not work in my case -- the stuff parameter winds up being null.  My data is not formatted exactly like your example.  Mine is:  stuff[key1]=value1&stuff[key2]=value2&...I'll see if there's something in your link to help me out with that format.

Comment: @RichM. That's the way the default `Model Binder` works, You can implement a custom one.

Comment: I'll look into the custom model binder.  Thanks.